# how to bind OpenGL sampler2d texture to fragment shader of SCNProgram in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, scenekit

I created an scnprogram and load vertex and fragment shaders for them.

```
let pro = SCNProgram()
var path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Shader", ofType: "vert")
do{
    let vertexShader = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: .utf8)
    pro.vertexShader = vertexShader
}catch{}
path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Shader", ofType: "frag")
do{
    let fragmentShader = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: .utf8)
    pro.fragmentShader = fragmentShader
}catch{}
```

the code for fragment shader is this:

```
uniform sampler2D ourTexture1; uniform sampler2D ourTexture2; void main() { vec4 tex1 = texture(ourTexture1, TexCoord); vec4 tex2 = texture(ourTexture2, TexCoord); color = vec4(mix(tex1.xyz, tex2.xyz, tex2.w), 1.0f); }
```

the code for generating textures are as follows :

```
var texture1:GLuint = 0
glGenTextures(1, &texture1)
glBindTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), texture1)

// Set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT (usually basic wrapping method)
glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S), GL_REPEAT)
glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T), GL_REPEAT)

// Set texture filtering parameters
glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER), GL_LINEAR)
glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER), GL_LINEAR)

// Load and generate the texture
let loader = SGLImageLoader(fromFile: "img.png")
if (loader.error != nil) { fatalError(loader.error!) }
let image = SGLImageRGB<UInt8>(loader)
if (loader.error != nil) { fatalError(loader.error!) }

// Create texture and generate mipmaps
image.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer() {
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB,
                 GLsizei(image.width),
                 GLsizei(image.height),
                 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                 $0.baseAddress)
}
glGenerateMipmap(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D))

glBindTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), 0)
```

for texture2, the code is the same as above. now my question is how to bind this generated textures to "uniform sampler2D ourTexture1" and "uniform sampler2D ourTexture2" of my fragment shader of SCNProgram?